# Manually change the timezone on windows 7 in one or two steps

Tags: time-zone

I need to change the timezone from CST(UTC-6) to IST and back to CST approx every hour. It is 6 steps work but having to do it every hour makes me tired. Can I make it simple like in one click?

Comment: What are you? Superman?

Comment: Jokes apart, read this: http://rickyspears.com/blog/2012/05/how-to-change-the-time-zone-in-windows-with-a-bat-file-script/

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked!! "tzutil /l" in command prompt gives the list of all the standard names.

Comment: I am really wondering why do you need to change the time zone approximately every hour. There could be a much better solution than doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
tzutil /l
```

to list all timezones.
Then create batch files to set timezones.
Example:

```
TZUTIL /s "Central Standard Time"
```

Then bind these batch files to hotkey using something like Autohotkey.